# Asking suggestion about where to find scientific papers

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm wondering if I can ask suggestion about where to find scientific papers concerning a specific topic on Stack Exchange site *[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour)* or in another Stack Exchange section.

Comment: Any particular area of science?

Comment: Hello @mdewey I'd like to find the original paper where there is the schedulability analysis for rate monotonic algorithm, when there are shared resources amongst the tasks. So it's a question about computer science.

Comment: Generally the right tool to find something on the internet is a search engine. There really aren't any sites here that will act as a proxy search engine for you.

Comment: GennaroArguzzi, simply finding a paper claiming *the best method* or a comparison of methods often leads to a list of referenced papers; possibly including what you are looking for: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/641267 **and**  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11241-018-9304-0

Comment: Hello @Rob thank you very much for your reply. I tried to follow your suggestion, but I get everytime the same references (Liu and Layland 1973). By the way I'm continuing to search by looking at references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many sites dedicated to specific sciences have so-called 'reference request' questions. Examples:

- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

Knowing where to find a specific paper requires domain knowledge, so therefore Academia Stack Exchange is not a good choice.